# How to pass intent from activity to fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hello am new to Android how to give intent from Activity to fragment?
I know from Fragment to Activity like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),nextActivity.class)
StartActivity(intent);
```

But I want from Activity to Fragment.

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent(currentActivity,nextFragement.class)
StartActivity(intent);

Comment: it doesn't works @AnjaliTripathi

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi that is not working with Activity to Fragment.

Comment: @chirag I was assuming that he needs to call FragmentActivity

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi *She needs.... :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pass the intent to the fragment, what you can do is get the data you have in the intent and pass it to the fragment. The recommended way to do that is to use the newInstance pattern.
So in the fragment you'll have this:

```
    public static MyFragment newInstance(@NonNull final String someId) {
        final MyFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(Const.KEY_SOME_ID, someId);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
```

To create the fragment of course you'll call that method.

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.KEY_ID);
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(id);
```

and to access it inside the fragment you need to get from arguments:

```
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        myId = args.getString(Const.KEY_SOME_ID, "");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working on Fragment.
use this code.

```
Fragment fragment =  new YourFragmentName();
if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        }
```

Where content_frame is

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in main layout

Answer (score -1):

In Activity you set data in intent

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("dataKey", "Value");
YourFragmentClass fragmentObject = new YourFragmentClass();
fragmentObject .setArguments(bundle);
if(fragmentObject!=null){
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentObject).commit();
    }
```

In Fragment's onCreateView method you can get the data

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

String activityData= getArguments().getString("dataKey");  

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```

}